# javascript function returning undefined even though value display in console.log

Tags: javascript

I've got this really annoying issue where a function returning a value of undefined every time even though the console.log() always shows that there is a value when getting into the first if statement

This is my function

```
function getElementIdentifier(elem, domSelector) {
    if(elem.getAttribute('id') !== null) {
        console.log('here');

        return elem.id + ' ' + domSelector;
    } else {
        getElementIdentifier(elem.parentNode, elem.tagName + ' ' + domSelector);
    }
}
```

This is how I call it

```
getElementIdentifier(elem, '');
```

Heres a fiddle to replicate it. http://jsfiddle.net/wqCSn/5/ (thanks @adeneo)

Comment: you miss return state in second branch and you check elem.getAttribute('id') but try to return elem.id -- do next return '' + elem.id + ' ' + domSelector;

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/wqCSn/

Comment: @null elem is incoming parametr

Comment: @VasilVanchuk I'm calling itself so dont need a return this.

Comment: @VasilVanchuk - there's the fact that the else statement calls the same function, and `element.id` and `element.getAttribute('id')` should return the same thing, otherwise something is really wrong.

Comment: @adeneo yep, call self, but not return result of this calling

Comment: Why would it return the result when it's recursive, it returns something if the condition is met on the next iteration.

Comment: @adeneo is correct. I'll only return something once my condition is met.

Comment: erhm... no, in order for you to catch the return value you need to return the value returned by the recursion. (sounds like inception)

Comment: @VasilVanchuk your correct. I put my hands up, I guess you learn something new everyday. If you put a solution down I'll mark it as correct as you was first correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function does not return value if call self recursively. You should to add return statement ro alternative branch of algorithm

```
function getElementIdentifier(elem, domSelector) {
    if(elem.getAttribute('id') !== null) {
        return elem.id + ' ' + domSelector;
    } else {
        return getElementIdentifier(elem.parentNode, elem.tagName + ' ' + domSelector);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hmmmm... try this:

```
function getElementIdentifier(elem, domSelector) {
 if(elem.getAttribute('id') !== null) {
    console.log('here');

    return elem.id + ' ' + domSelector;
 } else {
 //return the recursion returned value (sounds like inception) but
 //you are expecting a value from this function... 
    return getElementIdentifier(elem.parentNode, elem.tagName + ' ' + domSelector);
 }
}
```